# Should I call base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` like so:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userInRole = CurrentUser.IsInRole(Roles);

        // Etc...
    }
}
```

Should I be calling `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)` at all here?

If so, what would it do?

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation is open source and can be viewed [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs).

It checks whether the user is authenticated, then checks to ensure the user or role is specified on the attribute.

I guess the real question is, why are you writing a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` when the built-in one already does what you are doing?

Do note that it would be simpler to override the `AuthorizeCore` method (***instead of OnAuthorization***) if you really do need to customize it because the `OnAuthorization` method has code to disable output caching so cached views cannot be seen after logout.

Comment: It's just a learning exercise, not for production code.  It's a very crude implementation with hard coded users.  Good point about the  output caching.

Comment: An I missing something?  I've overridden `AuthorizeCore` and stuck a breakpoint in but it is never hit.

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute requires that it is placed on a controller, action method, or registered as a global filter. Also, the application must have a security framework in order for it to do anything. The simplest option is just to start with the default template that ships with Visual Studio (or add authorization to the template in some versions of Visual Studio) when you first create the project.