# When is AuthorizeCore hit?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I'm mucking about with `AuthorizeAttribute`.  It was suggesten in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32509273/442351) that I override `AuthorizeCore` rather than `OnAuthorize`.

I've got the demo code below:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("AuthorizeCore");
    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}

public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthorization");
}
```

`OnAuthorization` is hit, however `AuthorizeCore` is never hit.

Comment: When in doubt, always [view the source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). Justin is right, you need to call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)` in order for it to be called by `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: I think an even better approach -- in the most common cases -- is to simply delete your OnAuthorization call altogether and let the original run by itself. Then do what you need to do in an override to HandleUnauthorizedRequest.which will get called if AuthorizeCore returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source of [AuthorizeAttribute.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). **AuthorizeCore** is called inside **OnAuthorization**.

```
public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  ... 
  if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
  {
  }
  ...
}
```

### Solution

You need to call **base class' OnAuthorization** inside your **OnAuthorization** explicitly.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthorization");
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation doesn't call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)`.